# JavaScript colour changer doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, themes

Im trying to change the background colours of my website through button click but it doesn't work properly. What happens when i click the button it changes the colour and then turns back to the original colour instantly, it doesn't want to keep the changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").css("background", "grey");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> Change Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return false` in your button click. The button triggers a PostBack (Form Post). And then all the changes made to the UI will be lost. That is why it 'blinks' gray for a second and then changes back. It means that the page has finished reloading. Assuming you are using webforms or the button is inside a `form`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("div").css("background", "grey");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works for my homepage but if i go to a different page on my site it changes back again.

Comment: Of course it does. The other page does not know the color has changed. You need to store that in a Cookie or SessionStorage and apply it on the other pages as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla js version to do this would be:

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 200px; height:200px; "></div>
<button onclick="changeTheme()">Grey</button>
<script>
    function changeTheme() {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.background = "grey";
    }
</script>
```